# Grouping by id with consecutive one id

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 classes

```
   public class Log
   {
      public int Id {get;set;}
   }

   public class Conversation
   {
     public List<Log> Logs {get;set;}
   }
```

i got List and i want to return list of conversation when each conversation contains list of logs grouped by id with consecutive one id.
For example

i got list with 6 logs with ids 1,2,2,2,5,5 and i want to return 3 conversation  - first with 1 log 1 ,second with 3 logs 2 and third with 2 log 5

Thx for help and sorry for my bad eng

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: It's very unclear what you mean by "with one consecutive ID". Your sample sounds like it's just plain grouping by ID...

Comment: [How to: Group Query Results (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx)

Comment: i mean if i got list with 3 Logs and their ids are 1,2,1 it will be 3 separate conversation and becouse 1 is not  consecutive

Comment: So you want to group the elements without having `GroupBy` sort the whole list? I.e. only group consecutive elements?

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ:

```
var groups = Logs.
       GroupBy( log => log.Id ).ToList();
```